# How to find the X coordinate of a point on a line given another point of the line and the 2 points on a perpendicular line?

Tags: python, math, numpy

I'm writing a python app to select rectangular areas, when the user has set 2 points (the length of the rectangle), the third and 4th points are constrained in forming a rectangle, where the width of the rectangle is given by the Y difference of the mouse cursor and the last point.

Here's a quick picture to explain, I'm looking for the X coordinate of the point C.

[image]

I know :

- A(2,3)
- B(5,5)
- angle = 90 degrees
- the Y coordinate of C is 7.

I'm not sure how to tackle this... using vectors ? I'm using numpy in my project.

Comment: Did you get the solution of this question? I am facing same. Would you share your python code for help?

Comment: sorry for the late reply... I ended up using the `minAreaRect` method from the openCV lib that I was also using for this project. This is then no longer relevant to have the C point perpendicular to the A-B line, as I'm drawing a rectangle encompassing the 3 points:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minarearect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a math issue than a numpy issue.

The slope of (AB) is `(y_a - y_b)/ (a - b)`. So the slope of any perpendicular to (AB) is `p=(b-a)/(y_a-y_b)` (opposite of the inverse of the original slope).

From here it is easy to determine the equation of the perpendicular to (AB) passing through B : `y-y_b=p*(x-x_b)`. And substitute `y_c` to `y` to find `x_c`

There is an issue (division by zero) if (AB) is horizontal (0 slope). In that case, `x_c` is just `x_b` (all of the points on (BC) have same x coordinate)

Comment: nice answer! but what if instead of the perpendicular line of C going through B, it goes through any point between A and B. I know the coordinates A, B, and C, but I want to find out the coordinates of the point which the perpendicular crosses the AB line

Comment: @FMM ask another question, then :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217300/find-x-and-y-coordinates-where-a-perpendicular-point-crosses-a-straight-line