# Find x and y coordinates where a perpendicular point crosses a straight line

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry, trigonometry

This is a follow-up question to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606940/how-to-find-the-x-coordinate-of-a-point-on-a-line-given-another-point-of-the-lin/32607110?noredirect=1#comment97169459_32607110).

Taking the following image as an example:

[image]

What I know:

- `x` and `y` coordinates of points `D`, `E`, and `P`.
- Therefore, I also know slope and intercept of `D-E` line

What I want to know:

- `x` and `y` coordinates of point `Q`. (This is the point which crosses the `D-E` line).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry, not about computing.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com may be a better place for you, Also just Get line DE in form y=mx+b and then get perpindicular slope of m, call that m2, and get y-intercept of P line backtracking with its m2 slope so that it is also in form y=m2x2+b2, then subtract the two functions (mx+b)-(m2x2+b2), when that equals 0 they obviously are intersecting since the same value minus itself is the only time x-y=0... now that you have the x value of intersection plug it in to y=m2x2+b2 to solve for y-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation `P=[px,py], D=[dx,dy], E=[ex,ey], Q=[qx,qy]`

First:

```
R=P-D=[px-dx, py-dy]=[rx,ry]

K=E-D=[ex-dx, ey-dy]=[kx, ky]
```

Then

```
z=dot(R,K)/dot(K,K)=(rx*kx+ry*ky) / (kx*kx+ky*ky)
```

Finally

```
Q=D+z*K=[dx+z*kx, dy+z*ky]
```

The R is vector which start on point D and ends on point K, the K is vector which start on point D and ends on point E. Using this we made scalar projection to calculate result Q. More info about concept [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_first_properties)